# calculate $E(e^{B(t)}|e^{B(u)},0\le u\le s )$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $\{B_t,t\ge0\}$ be a standard brownian motion and suppose $0\le u\le s<t$, calculate $E(e^{B(t)}|e^{B(u)},0\le u\le s )$.

Attempts: $E(e^{B(t)}|e^{B(u)},0\le u\le s )=E(e^{B(t-u)+B(u)}|e^{B(u)})=E(e^{B(t-u)}|e^{B(u)})E(e^{B(u)}|e^{B(u)})$ but then not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $B(t)\ne B(t-u)+B(u)$.

Comment: @did i see $B(t-u)\sim~N(0,\sqrt{t^2+u^2})$

Comment: No, this is not the distribution of $B(t-u)$.

Comment: OP: What happens with this question? Did you manage to write down a full proof, using @Stefan's hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $B_t=B_t-B_s+B_s$ and use that 
$$
E[XY\mid\mathcal{G}]=XE[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]
$$
if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable along with the fact that
$$
E[X\mid\mathcal{G}]=E[X]
$$
if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Also knowing the MGF for a normal random variable will come in handy.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Indeed!